# Multilingual text not copied when using an event template to create an event

Tags: civievent, templates, multilingual

I am running a new multilingual (en & fr) civi site an making extensive use of templates for multiple event types. The templates are created with text in the appropriate language blocks on each field. However, when I create an event using such a template, only one of the languages gets copied across into the new event. If I create an event while my civicrm language is set to english then the english text is copied into BOTH language blocks. Likewise if civicrm language is set to french then the french text goes into both. I have replicated this on a fresh civi install. Can anyone indicate if this is a restriction, a bug or a misconfiguration on my part. Thanks in advance.

Civi=5.27.1 / Drupal=7.72 / PHP = 7.3.21 / mySQL=5.5.60

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.  If you have an event template with English and French and you create a new event using that template, I'd expect the new event to have English and French content identical to the template.

I'd suggest opening an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Comment: Yes, I sort of thought that would be the case bu wanted to verify before reporting as a bug.  Sadly there are so many inconsistencies and minor bugs when running multilingual civi. For future projects I would seriously consider whether this is the best route or not. Perhaps using alternatives such as running single language and putting both languages into each text box, title, description etc.. Thanks for your input.

Comment: For what it's worth it looks like this was fixed: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2479